# Does 2g/3g rf receive circuit path work for 4g if they are in the same band?

Tags: transceiver, mobile

I am wondering that if the rf receive path for gsm/wcdma can be used to receive lte fdd signals? provided that gsm/wcdma/lte are in the same band e.g. band8 downlink frequency 925-960mhz, and the transreceiver support all these bands.

Signals from antenna pass switch/lna/filter to transceiver, along the way all the process units are related to physical frequency rather than logical network protocol, so I think it should work for whatever network built on the same frequency band. So I can use gsm saw filters/baluns for the same band lte receive path?

Please correct me if Im wrong, thank you very much.

Update:

Specifically, I want to use fdd band8 downlink analog path(from asm to transceiver), to receive wcdma/gsm band8 signals, is this possible and practical?

Comment: updated my answer. No surprises there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: What did you expect? Even if in the same band, 4G OFDM and 3G CDMA / FDM signals are far far broader than 2G, and to receive GSM's GMSK, you really don't need an overly linear or large-dynamic range analog chain, very much unlike especially the 4G waveforms.

In fact, LTE is designed for IQ mixers. That's not inherently the architecture of  2G devices. Technological differences would make it overly hard to reuse a 2G architecture for 4G. What about frequency stability, non-linearity, channel hopping (including the fact that GSM transceivers have filters for 200 kHz wide channels), higher demands in coherency of LOs, worse effect of phase noise (kills especially CDMA very quickly)?

Historically, we invented a 4G that is incompatible to 2G to overcome the analog limits that the 2G receivers and transmitters pose. So, there's really not much to be won here by trying to reuse technology that is 30 years old.

**Update**

> I want to use fdd band8 downlink analog path(from asm to transceiver), to receive wcdma/gsm band8 signals, is this possible and practical?

For the reasons statet above, no, it's not practical.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! the application I face to is that I have a 4g transceiver that support lte/wcdma/gsm, and the reference design has dedicated diversity path for wcdma(gsm?). as you said lte bandwidth is broader than gsm, then I want to know if I can reuse analog down path from fdd in gsm receive of the same band. Again, the modem/transceiver support all module schems like psk, qam and duplex schems like ofdm. Im not trying to take old hardware to accomdate new technoligy, but want use the new be compatible to the old. try to support more bands under a limited swtich throws.

Comment: This should not be a comment, but part of your question, or a new question. But as said, 2G receiver chains aren't optimized for non-constant-envelope signals, and don't offer much linearity. I don't know your precise system, so you'll have to do the math yourself.

Comment: yes you're right, but I'm not good at math, shame...